# When to use the pronoun "es"?

Tags: grammar, pronoun

I am not a German native speaker.
I know that in certain situations the pronoun "es" has a different usage
than the English "it", but I am not sure when it should be used and when it shouldn't.

Here are two examples I would like to ask some clarifications for.

*Example 1*:

> I want to translate: "A new book will be presented tomorrow". My
>   intuition tells me: "Es wird morgen ein neues Buch präsentiert." but I
>   am not sure about this. Is it correct to start the sentence with es if
>   the subject is missing or is not the first element of the sentence?

*Example 2*:

> A slightly more complex example. "Moreover it would be interesting for
>   me to..." Translation: "Darüber hinaus wäre es für mich interessant,
>   ... zu ..."

Is it correct to put "es" in this case? Or should I simply write
"Darüber hinaus wäre für mich interessant, ... zu ..."?

Comment: Instinkt ist angeboren. Die Sprache ist nicht angeboren. Was immer zu Dir in sprachlichen Angelegenheiten spricht - der Instinkt ist es nicht.

Comment: Ich meinte mein intuitives Verständnis: ich würde es so sagen aber ich kann nicht erklären warum.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> "Es wird morgen ein neues Buch präsentiert."

is correct. It sounds a little better when you change the word order and omit the *es*:

> "Morgen wird ein neues Buch präsentiert."

Your second example:

> "Darüber hinaus wäre es für mich interessant, ...
>
> "Darüber hinaus wäre für mich interessant, ... zu ..."

Both sentences are correct in my opinion.

Comment: The only thing I would add is that using the "es" in this case makes it into "there" in English, like "es wird" = "there is/will be" and so on. That's probably what you meant by "a different usage than the English 'it'". Its inclusion or exclusion works the same way in both languages.

Comment: My feelling is, that "Es wird morgen *ein neues Buch* präsentiert" puts an emphasis on the book, e.g. as an answer to the question "was wird eigentlich morgen vorgestellt?". The word order that splattne gave has not such emphasis IMO.

On a second note: I don't like these language constructs which omit the persons acting, because they sound a little bit impersonal (duh).

Answer (score -3):

I would say when referring to a generic everyman, like using "one" in English or "on" in French. But closer to how it's used in French, outside of a certain meme, it sounds a little awkward in English.

Comment: Are you confusing *man* with *es*?

Comment: um, maybe... *disappears into shrubs*